# What is a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I know what a `UIView` is but not a `UIViewController`. I just want to know what I could use it for, and what it is compared to a `UIView`

Comment: Please refer to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for such questions.

Comment: Lamens terms please. I have already read the documentation and still don't understand it that well. That is why I am asking this question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically you need to know, what is [model-view-controller architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) in the software engineering field, the `UIView` corresponds to view of this architecture and `UIViewController` is at controller side of this architecture.

Now `UIViewController` can be thought as an agent that controls (and has the implementations of methods) the events and design of the `UIView` that is shown on the screen. Anything you want to change on the view can be written inside a method in its controller class, that inherits itself from `UIViewController` class. That is only the brief description of this big concept. For details you should look for the above link.

Comment: Thank you I just didn't understand what the documentation said entirely. You helped me greatly. Thanks so much.